# I am getting the overflow error while trying to change a number into a date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am trying to convert numbers -> specified date format. This is being done only on one column (column D). Here is the code -

```
'Changing date format (for UPLOADDATE column)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row)
    c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
    c.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Now, whenever my code reaches this point - it breaks with the following error being displayed :-

Run-time error '6':
Overflow

What my code does, overall, is to copy data from another excel file to a hidden sheet of the excel (where the code is located). update the column with the date format (as specified in the above code) and then update all the pivot tables in the file.

Note - I DO set the visibility of the hidden sheet as true before changing the format of the column

Comment: have you verified that the cell value can be converted w/o any error checking first?  Perhaps you're trying to convert something that can't be converted...

Comment: ok so here is an updated problem - when I copy paste the data, the data in the pasted column somehow changes its format to something liek ########, when it is supposed to be like 20140908, hence the code is unable to convert the values...what should be done in this case?

Comment: In case of numbers ####### means that it is a -ve value

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry for being dense, but what is a -ve value?

Comment: @sous2817: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182247

Comment: @SiddharthRout Outstanding, thanks!

Comment: @SiddharthRout - thanks for the comments! I was able to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because the cell either has a negative value or a very large value formatted as a date. You may want to see the explanation for [########](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182247)

See this example

[image]

Test Code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = Range("B3")

    Debug.Print DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
End Sub
```

[image]

Step through the code and check what is the address of the cell C and then manually check what that cell contains.

One way of finding the offending cell address is using the error handling. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = Range("B3")

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Debug.Print DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "The Error Happened in " & c.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so I removed the column and then put a new one in place (i.e. in the sheet where the data is being pasted) - now its working (I have checked multiple times). Although, this answer of yours is really useful for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're code first copies the numbers into `ThisWorkbook`, then attempts to convert them to a `Date` object?  Is it possible that when you ask Excel to copy numbers into `ThisWorkbook`, that Excel is auto-detecting that its copying dates formatted as numbers and immediately converting the numbers to `Date` objects?

You didn't provide a sample of the number format that you're copying from, although I think I can infer one from the values passed to:

```
DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
```

Something like "yyyymmdd" or "yyyy/mm/dd" ?

If you try to manually paste (using `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V`) numbers formatted as such into Excel you'll notice that Excel automatically converts those values into `Date` objects.

You could test this by leaving copies of the code's work at various points in its execution.

Comment: I tried this - removed all the code except the copying part, excel does not automatically convert the data while pasting it...